# localhost xampp curl port 80 error

Tags: php, curl

I seem to be having an issue with a single url endpoint while `cUrl` from local xampp.
I get an error message of `Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused` even when I set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);`.

But this **only happens from a particular url (without ssl http://)**, other urls with https:// is fine. And all other cUrl to different endpoints are fine.
On a live server, the problematic endpoint, same code everything works fine.

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening?

My http.conf: `ServerName localhost:80`

complete code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    // "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
    // "Connection: keep-alive",
    // "Keep-Alive: 300",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    'Api-Key: ' . $apiKey,
    ));

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    //curl_easy_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $httpHeaders = curl_getinfo($ch);


    curl_close($ch);


    print_r($ch);
    echo $httpcode;
    print_r($httpHeaders);
    print_r($errmsg); // Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused
```

after spending the entire day, **the fix** was to set an empty value for proxy and use port 80

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, ''); //!! FIX
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
```

Comment: I am on windows, is there an equivalent?

Comment: Something is using your port 1080

Comment: @omerowitz ran `netstat -a -b ` dont see anything from my end using port 1080

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , i solved it by running apache on other port,  you should to edit your httpd.conf

Comment: my conf file has `ServerName localhost:80 `  what would you suggest?

Comment: I suggest with 4290 or 3000 .